# Is there any way to check for browser javascript support in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was wondering if there was any way to check for browser javascript support in sinatra so I can feed it into a template, allowing me to create js and non js page version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't test for JavaScript on serverside. What you can do is render a page that has a JS redirect:

```
window.location.replace("index-with-js.html");
```

You will land on the JS version only if the redirect is executed, which effectively tests for JS support.